# Import-Module in Powershell not working when called from PHP

Tags: php, powershell

PHP File

```
            header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            $psPath = "powershell.exe -executionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -File  C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ps_file.ps1";
            exec($psPath , $output, $retval);
```

Powershell File ps_file.ps1

```
            Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Code 1

```
            <!-- The below code does not work !>
            Import-Module ActiveDirectory
            return Get-ADUser user1
            # nothing is returned
            # ActiveDirectory module is installed on the server correctly and is working fine when I run Import-Module ActiveDirectory, Get-ADUser directly from the PS file.
```

Code 2

```
            <!-- The below code works !>
            return hostname
            # returns hostname succesfully
```

I am successfully able to reach the PS file using PHP, which is why code 2 works, however Code 1 does not work. Code 1 succesfully works directly from the PS file though

Comment: As aside, why `-InputFormat none` (twice) ?

Comment: @Theo will fix that .. can that be a cause ?

Comment: You've got `-ExecutionPolicy` twice, too.

Comment: @Bacon Bits have corrected that, the issue still persists

Comment: Does ANY powershell-specific command work? Using `hostname` is not really testing like for like.

Comment: @Scepticalist  , ipconfig works, returning a string works ... if(Import-Module ActiveDirectory){} does not work if(1 -eq 1){} works ..

Comment: `Import-Module` cmdlet does not generate any output by default so `if(Import-Module ActiveDirectory){}` does not give any sense. @Scepticalist asks _Does ANY powershell-specific command work_, e.g. `return Get-Command hostname`?

Comment: @JosefZ return Get-ADUser user1 does not work, but when I run return Get-ADUser user1 from the ps1 file directly, it works

Comment: Please read @Scepticalist's comment again and follow my one. Would `return Get-Command hostname` work if the script is invoked _from PHP_? You could try `Import-Module ActiveDirectory -PassThru` instead.

Comment: @JosefZ, when calling from PHP,  return hostname works,  but Import-Module ActiveDirectory return Get-ADUser user1 does not work, am new to Powershell so maybe i am not able to explain correctly

Comment: Again: not `return hostname` but `return Get-Command hostname` !!!

Comment: @JosefZ from PHP return Get-Command hostname does not return anything, but when I run Get-Command hostname from the PS file, it returns data

Comment: Therefore your PHP code is not running Powershell correctly at all. It's not specific to Import-Module. Commands like `ipconfig` and `hostname` are not Powershell commands.

Comment: @Scepticalist , that makes sense, but how come --  if(1 -eq 1){return some string} works if i call the PS file from PHP -- if condition is Powershell right ? (I am new to PS hence the confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Transcript to your .ps1 to find out what exactly is actually being executed:

```
Start-Transcript -Path '\\path to writable folder\transcript.txt
Try {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
    $Userdetail = Get-ADUser user1 -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    $_
}
Stop-Transcript
Return $Userdetail
```

Comment: transcript helped a ton, it was a permission issue, adding admin service account credentials in the PS script helped, as PHP was taking windows/system as default user with less permission